# Using VB.net to write an Ebay Motors Pro xml file

Tags: mysql, xml, vb.net, xmlwriter

I am struggling to make this work and have trawled for examples on how to fix this to no avail.  I am converting a mysql resultset into an xml file to upload to ebaymotorspro.  I thought this would be relatively simple and yet I am struggling with the conventions set out by both ebay and the .net framework.

The opening element of the file has to read:

```
<empro xmlns="urn:de:mobile:emp:inventory:xml:uk:car" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:de:mobile:emp:inventory:xml:uk:car http://www.ebaymotorspro.co.uk/schema/empro-car-uk.xsd">
```

I am using the xmlwriter class to recreate this and have this so far:

```
Using writer as XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(feedfile, xmlsettings)
    writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
    writer.WriteStartElement("empro", "urn:de:mobile:inventory:xml:uk:car")

    ' This Bit is causing the issue
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScema-instance")

End Using
```

I end up with the following code in the xml file:

```
<empro p1:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p1="xmlns" xmlns="urn:de:mobile:emp:inventory:xml:uk:car" />
```

Which isnt correct, can anyone please point me in the right direction to make this output the correct document header?

Many thanks
Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part that causing you a trouble should've been written using `WriteAttributeString()` overload [which accept four parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z46xs1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
' This Bit is causing the issue'
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", Nothing, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLScema-instance")
```

Anyway, I will personally do this using [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx). VB even has exclusive features which C# doesn't for constructing XML : XML literals with embedded expression support. For example :

```
Dim contactName As String = "Patrick Hines"
Dim contact As XElement =
  <contact><%= contactName %></contact>
Console.WriteLine(contact.ToString())
'output :'
'<contact>Patrick Hines</contact>'
```

Source : [MSDN: Creating XML in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384808.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @har07 for your help, it worked very well.  The only thing I have noticed is that ebay show them in a specific order and my code produces them out of order.  Is this likely to be an issue?

Comment: I don't think so. Given ebay treats your xml as xml (they really should), not as string literal